# EAS build on iOS fails with: The following build commands failed: PhaseScriptExecution

Tags: xcode, expo, eas

So I'm trying to build my expo app with "eas build" for iOS. Building for android works completely fine, but whenever I build it for iOS, I get this error in the console:

```
** ARCHIVE FAILED **
The following build commands failed:

PhaseScriptExecution [CP-User]\ Generate\ Specs /Users/expo/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/SALMobile-egdwlhlmnbjnybcxyqfforltlppo/Build/Intermediates.noindex/ArchiveIntermediates/SALMobile/IntermediateBuildFilesPath/Pods.build/Release-iphoneos/FBReactNativeSpec.build/Script-46EB2E00014760.sh (in target 'FBReactNativeSpec' from project 'Pods')
```

In the Xcode logs i get this:

```
/bin/sh -c /Users/expo/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/SALMobile-egdwlhlmnbjnybcxyqfforltlppo/Build/Intermediates.noindex/ArchiveIntermediates/SALMobile/IntermediateBuildFilesPath/Pods.build/Release-iphoneos/FBReactNativeSpec.build/Script-46EB2E00014760.sh
/bin/sh: /Users/expo/workingdir/build/React: No such file or directory
Command PhaseScriptExecution failed with a nonzero exit code
```

my package.json:

```
{
  "name": "salmobile",
  "version": "1.0.1",
  "scripts": {
  "start": "expo start",
  "android": "expo run:android",
  "ios": "expo run:ios",
  "web": "expo start --web"
},
"dependencies": {
  "@expo/cli": "^0.10.11",
  "@expo/config-plugins": "6.0.0",
  "@expo/prebuild-config": "^6.0.0",
  "@react-native-community/datetimepicker": "6.7.3",
  "@react-navigation/bottom-tabs": "^6.5.8",
"@react-navigation/material-top-tabs": "^6.6.3",
"@react-navigation/native": "^6.1.2",
  "@react-navigation/native-stack": "^6.9.8",
  "axios": "^1.2.2",
  "expo": "~48.0.18",
  "expo-device": "~5.2.1",
  "expo-notifications": "~0.18.1",
  "expo-secure-store": "~12.1.1",
  "expo-splash-screen": "~0.18.2",
  "expo-status-bar": "~1.4.4",
  "metro": "^0.77.0",
  "metro-config": "^0.77.0",
  "react": "18.2.0",
  "react-native": "0.71.2",
  "react-native-cli": "^2.0.1",
  "react-native-dropdown-select-list": "^2.0.4",
  "react-native-gesture-handler": "~2.9.0",
  "react-native-global-state-hooks": "^3.0.5",
  "react-native-pager-view": "^6.1.2",
  "react-native-paper": "^5.1.3",
  "react-native-reanimated": "~2.14.4",
  "react-native-safe-area-context": "^4.5.0",
  "react-native-screens": "~3.20.0",
  "react-native-tab-view": "^3.5.2"
},
"devDependencies": {
  "@babel/core": "^7.12.9"
},
"private": true
```

}

I went through every possible solution I found online but nothing worked. Anyone have any ideas? Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

I found the soultion myself:

I created the project in a diffrent directory than the one i built it in.
I didn't find any solution to this, so I just copied the entire project into the original folder and built it from there.

Hope this helps